# Disable Jarallax from loading on browser widths smaller than 768px

Tags: jquery, html, css, jquery-plugins, parallax

I'm not the best at jQuery so I could use some help on this. I'm building a responsive site and would like to have the Jarallax animations disabled for browsers with a width of less than 768px. For a working example and example of the code, you can check out:

http://www.2gis.ru/dr/

Any help would be appreciated.